# R data.frame explanation of results

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have 3 vectors: `MRI`, `MRI_high`, `MRI_low`. With the `_low` and `_high` being half the length of the first. My objective is to put them into one same element, so that I can make iterations (I have a bunch of vectors following same format)

When I wrote: `data.entry(MRI, MRI_high, MRI_low)` A window popped up with my data arranged in columns and of correct length, problem, I cant use that.
When I used `MRI_vector <- data.frame(MRI, MRI_high, MRI_low)` The function somehow gave me 3 elements of equal length, by duplicating the shorter lists.

What is a solution to this? And do data frames need equal lengths for their elements?

Moreover, I tried using lists, however my values are then not numerical

Comment: A dataframe is a table, and typically in a table every column has the same number of rows - so yes, you need equal lengths.

Answer (score 0):

One option will be to place them in a `list` and pad with NA to make the `length`s equal before converting to 'data.frame'

```
lst <- mget(ls(pattern = "MRI.*"))
df1 <- data.frame(lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))))
```

Comment: I am confused, How do I manage to add the NA, if compute correlations for example, will the NA be ignored?

Comment: @rannoudanames  I am not sure what you meant.  The above solution creates a `data.frame` by padding NA for vector that has less number of elements so as to keep the length same.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem:

I used the list, however, when computing statistics I used `as.numeric(unlist())` which still allows me to iterate.

Although any further comments on this are appreciated for me to understand this strange data-frame behaviour!